What are morphologies in star clusters?
While studying astronomy, I came across the term morphologies of stellar clusters, and I don't understand how that works. For context, I came across the term "The embedded stellar clusters in NGC 1333 follow what morphology? Turbulent, Centralized, Hierarchial, Distributed" I'm less interested in finding the answer to this question, but more interested in finding what all these morphologies mean in the context of astronomy.

Can you provide a link to where you came across that quote?

Some of those four may be fictitious, not applicable to any cluster.
